# Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud unsubscribe synching

Tags: marketing-cloud

Recently I have been setting up a few automations to ensure proper synchronization of different fields from Sales Cloud to attribute fields in Marketing Cloud.

I also wanted to set up an automation to synch Email Opt Outs.

According to the documentation:

> Enabling the Email Opt Out field only in Sales or Service Cloud does
>   not synchronize the subscriber status in the Marketing Cloud. Always
>   click Marketing Cloud Unsubscribe on the record (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_unsubscribes.htm&type=5)

While I was testing, I found that the status of a subscriber was synching instantly and correctly when the Email Opt Out field was checked, even though I haven't set up any automation for this yet.
In Sales Cloud we are using the HasOptedOutOfEmail field and it gets correctly reflected in All Subscribers list.

Has there been an update recently, or am I missing a piece of puzzle here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to log a "correct" unsubscription (= log an Event in Unsubscribe Table + set Status in All Subscribers) in Marketing Cloud is by using the LogUnsubEvent method.

- Checking the Box "hasOptedOutOfEmail" (Label: Email Opt Out) on Lead or Contact alone does not leverage LogUnsubEvent. There should be no visible "cross cloud" effect by simply checking that box in Sales Cloud on the Contact or Lead. I just reconfirmed that in a test, as this would indeed be surprising and somewhat "new".
- Clicking the custom button "Marketing Cloud Unsubscribe" on Lead / Contact Page Layout, which is part of the MC Connect setup instructions DOES leverage it. 
  In my interpretation, the sole reason why this button exists is the point above - The checkbox alone doesn't cut it.
- Standard SFMC Unsubscription Center DOES leverage logUnsubEvent.
- Using the correct AMPScript / SSJS Code snippets DOES leverage it in custom unsubscription processes.
- list-unsubscribe / reply-unsubscribe DOES leverage it.
- Manually unsubscribing through the All Subscribers UI DOES leverage it.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: this pertains to single org / single BU behavior; discussion on multi org / multi BU here:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324329/in-an-integrated-multi-org-implementation-how-does-the-default-sf-emailoptout/324358#324358

Comment: Just to add to this list: clicking on "Unsubscribe" in Gmail will also update the SFCRM Contact Record to hasoptedoutofemail = "true"

Comment: That IS list unsub, @ChristopherCarswell - https://sendgrid.com/blog/list-unsubscribe/#:~:text=List%2Dunsubscribe%20is%20an%20optional,sender%20as%20spam%20or%20junk.

Comment: Good to know.  In the All Subscribers, it's just "Subscriber Unsubscribe" which doesn't say much (and I haven't found any supporting document).

Answer (score 1):

Email Opt Out does not affect Unsubscribe in All subscribers list, which is confirmed by the support material from salesforce as per the OP's comment

Email Opt Out only reflects in Contact Builder for the field 'HasOptedOutOfEmail'.

**Screenshot of Email Opt Out - Sales Cloud**

[image: emailoptout]

**Screenshot of HasOptedOutOfEmail - Marketing Cloud**

[image: hasoptedoutofemail]

**Screenshot of Unsubscribe - Marketing Cloud**

[image: unsubscribe]

Answer (score -3):

It's part of Marketing Cloud connect feature....Whenever you update the change in 'HasOptedOutOfEmail' it will automatically update in All-subscriber list.

Comment: Hi razor - accodring to the official documentation, it is not: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_unsubscribes.htm&type=5 - do you have any links confirming this?

Comment: It's on the same link which you have posted.https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_unsubscribes.htm&type=5....."The status of a subscriber changes from Active to Unsubscribed in Marketing Cloud and the Email Opt Out field is enabled in Sales or Service Cloud when any of the following occurs:

A subscriber clicks the Unsubscribe link in an email or the profile center.
You click Marketing Cloud Unsubscribe on a contact, lead, or person account record in Sales or Service Cloud."

Comment: we don't use "Marketing Cloud Unsubscribe", we use the standard "Email Opt Out" field

Comment: please see this as a reference: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172556/how-can-i-update-all-subscriber-list-status-field-to-unsubscribe-from-salesfor

Comment: Yes It comes as part of that, so when you click on 'Marketing Cloud Un-subscribe' it also marked as 'Checked' in Email Opt out field and also updates in 'All-subscriber list' in SFMC. Similarly...If you make change in Email Opt out field it will also update 'All-subscriber' list.