# Does Unsubscribing a subscriber manually (Marketing Cloud) opts him out in Salesforce?

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscribe, preference-center

Developing a custom profile center that needs to sync opt-ins/outs to Salesforce,
to then be propagated to Pardot.

According to this documentation:

There are multiple ways to unsubscribe a subscriber from receiving communications.

1. A subscriber opts out by clicking the link to the profile center included in each email. The user is unsubscribed in the Marketing Cloud and the Email Opt Out flag is checked in the CRM.
2. A subscriber can click a link to a custom profile center and opt in or out of specific communications.
3. A Salesforce user can unsubscribe or opt out a subscriber manually within the CRM.
4. A Marketing Cloud user can unsubscribe or opt out a subscriber manually in Marketing Cloud.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_tracking_and_unsubscribes_faqs.htm&type=5

So, for #1 it's clear. And #3 is also ok.

**But what about scenarios #2 and #4?**

- For #2 - If we use the LogUnSubEvent - would that update Salesforce via MC Connect?
- For #4 - Do manual Unsubscribe updates in Marketing Cloud propagate to Salesforce to update the OptOut field? (Which I guess refers to the **hasOptedOutOfEmail** field?)

**LogUnSubEvent Doc:**
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#2: yes

#4: yes

LogUnsubEvent and the connector can be considered integrated. Every "real" marketing cloud unsubscription leverages LogUnsubEvent including your examples.

see also:
[Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud unsubscribe synching](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252062/sales-cloud-to-marketing-cloud-unsubscribe-synching/293707#293707)

Comment: Thanks, @Jonas,  What about the re-subscribe scenario? i.e. does that reflect in the CRM?

Comment: tbh, i think that should go in a separate question; if you're talking about #2, custom preference center - you have to use updateSingleSalesforceObject and set the hasOptedOutOfEmail field to false again. There is no kind of "logResubscribeEvent" neither as an operation nor is there a data view table in Marketing Cloud that it would populate. Which is a large part of the point of LogUnsubEvent.

Comment: Agreed, should be a different question.
There is actually another question to be asked related to this one: Do Manual re-subscribes and "Default Subscription" center resubscribes sync to the CRM? (i.e. set the hasOptedOutOfEmail to false again.