# In an integrated, multi-org implementation, how does the default SF "EmailOptOut" button work?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, unsubscribe, preference-center

Ok, I have two MC business units attached to one CRM instance. Both BUs are set for "Unsubscribe subscribers from this business unit only." But Salesforce only has ONE EmailOptOut field on the Contact record. If I want to create separate preference centers for each, is it as simple as just creating another EmailOptOut field on the Contact record and using that for the second business unit? Is there anything inherent in the standard EmailOptOut field that I'm missing?

As I understand it, that field will keep people from being included on a SFS report or campaign, but does not necessarily affect MC subscriber status. Just trying to figure out what role it plays in a multi-org situation.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252062/sales-cloud-to-marketing-cloud-unsubscribe-synching is a good reference for single BU. Furthermore, you may want to consider using the [Consent framework](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=consent_mgmt_fields.htm&type=5) on the core cloud side for storing sub/unsub preferences. Maybe overkill vs simple checkboxes or might not be, depending on how much of that is needed on the core side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

single org behavior is linked in the comment above.

Multi-Org SFMC setups, as well as multiple BUs in Single Org (there is no difference in this regard) simply do not work with the standard MC Connect offering.

In the words of the documentation

> "Marketing Cloud Connect does not support business unit-level unsubscribes for Enterprise 2.0 accounts. Subscribers are included in the All Subscribers list at the enterprise level and unsubscribed from all business units in the enterprise"

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_unsubscribes.htm&type=5

As you rightly state, there is only one "HasOptedOutOfEmail" field. In a multi BU setup, what actually happens is the following:

*No matter where* you unsubscribe, and no matter what setting that BU has, *any* logUnsubEvent unsubscription will set this field to "true". I have tested this and documented it step by step because the first time I saw it, I couldn't believe it (and the docs weren't so explicit at the time).

The alternative is not to stop using LogUnsubEvent, though, as this is the only way your unsubs create statistics, work with Einstein etc. Also, it is the only way you stay consistent with other standards - no matter your custom implementation, List-unsubscribe Header in Commercial Emails will *keep* logging unsub events and will keep setting "HasOptedOutOfEmail" to true. So you can't really stop it from reoccuring. I have no official statistics on this, but I checked in some implementations and saw up to 10% list-unsubscriptions, so this does carry some weight.

So the alternative - in my book - must be to let the connector do its thing quietly, forget about the standard field, potentially hide it, forget about campaigns and reports for sendout segmentation, create a custom preference center and make sure your permissions are still logged (LogUnsubevent), tracked etc. in a custom implementation.

If you do not want or cannot stop using campaigns and reports for sendout segmentation, then make sure that this implementation also controls "HasOptedOutOfEmail" and reverts it to "false" after keeping track of your unsubscriptions and enforcing their *intended* effect (a more targeted unsubscription) in other ways.